# Is there a problem with a .Net 2.0 app receiving inbound data on a server that requires TLS 1.2?

Tags: .net, ssl, iis-8, tls1.2

We recently disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 for inbound traffic on a server and we have stopped receiving data to one of our web services that is built on .Net 2.0.  I've searched all over and found a ton of information about the TLS handshake, but what I can't verify is whether or not the application on my server receiving the inbound data needs to be able to support TLS 1.2 (i.e. rebuild to > 4.5)

I know that the application calling the service endpoint must support 1.2 in order to negotiate with the host server, but is the inbound server where that negotiation ends, or is the hosted application also required to support TLS 1.2?

Comment: Clearly Microsoft dedicated a section for your scenario, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#if-your-app-targets-net-framework-35 You also should learn tools like Wireshark so as to analyze the actual TLS handshake packets to confirm that your changes do resolve the issue.

Comment: @LexLi unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question I'm asking.  If my server requires 1.2 for all inbound, will my .Net 2.0 app need to be updated in order for an outside client to call my app?